# Django login error when using incorrect username and password on AWS

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I've spent many hours trying to solve this error but I'm stuck.

On my local server, when I try to log in with an incorrect email or password, I get the proper error message from the login view on my HTML template. However on my production server, when I try to sign in with an incorrect email and password I get this error in my browser.

I feel like this has something to do with uwsgi.

ValueError at /login/
invalid method signature

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http:// My Public IP Address :8000/login/
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
invalid method signature
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.8/inspect.py, line 1808, in _signature_bound_method
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:
['.',
'',
'/usr/lib/python38.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.8',
'/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
'/home/ubuntu/startup/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 13 Nov 2020 19:55:38 +0000

Code Login HTML

```
        <div class="login">
        <form action="{% url 'login_new' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <h1 class="heading_login_signup">Login</h1>

                {{ form.username.errors }}
                <label class="label_block_bold_colored_red">Email</label>
                
                {{ form.password.errors }}
                <label class="label_block_bold_colored_red">Password</label>
                
            </div>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login">

        </form>

            <div class="login_error">
                {% if messages %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        {{ message }}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}             
            </div>
            <div>
```

Login Views.py

```
def login_new(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user=form.get_user()
        login(request,user)
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Incorrect Email or Password")
        return redirect('login_new')
else:
    form = AuthenticationForm

return render(request, 'pages/index.html', {'form':form} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, after hours of coding I figured it out. Issue was with django version. I was running version 3.1.3. I downgraded to 3.0.5 and the issue was solved!